# Localized time with leading zero

Tags: android

Under my locale `DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(...)` gives me `8:28 AM`. Is there any way to get localized time but with leading zero (that is, `08:28 AM` in my case) - I mean without hardcoding pattern etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have 24H format time you can do something like this using kotlin extensions:

```
fun Long.formatTime(): String? {
  val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
  calendar.time = Date(this)

  val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
  val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

  return String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute)
}
```

**EDITED**

If you still did't find the solution

```
 val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
 print(dateFormat.format(Date()))
```

This prints

> 08:24 AM

Comment: True, but I also need AM/PM part - but it's locale specific, for example won't be the same under French locale. Following your approach I'd basically have to keep templates for all the possible time formats. I could use time formats directly but that's not what I want.

Comment: Updated the response.

Comment: I think there is a problem with this approach. For example this `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.FRANCE).format(new Date())` is currently producing "04:58 AM" on my environment. But in France there are no AM/PMs.

Comment: That's probably, cause you don't have French locale installed on your device.